# Best way to start with Angular 5 - Updated resources needed

Tags: angular, web, angular5, boilerplate

I'm about to learn Angular 5, due to requirements at the work. As Angular 7 is actual nowadays, probably Angular 5 slowly becomes deprecated, and online resources become a little bit old, I would ask here what are the best/most updated resources to learn it? 
I searched through Udemy (can buy any course via company) and there is bunch of courses, generally short ones (few hours). Can someone mention best of them?
Started with Angular official docs and installed ng-cli which is version 7 at the moment. I need exactly Angular 5, and good tutorial to create app with for example: login/register, router, some public/protected pages etc. Anyone can help?

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources are considered off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

These are some websites i found useful when i worked with angular 5:

- https://toddmotto.com/angular/
- https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/
- https://alligator.io/angular/

and the official docs for angular 5 is more than enough : https://v5.angular.io/docs